# Speeding up a SQL procedure that executes a Python script via Machine Learning Services

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL procedure that my web site calls thousands of times per day. The procedure executes a Python script. My problem is that it's taking too long to execute (about 6 seconds), and over half of the run time is spent importing libraries and loading objects for the script to use.

```
exec sp_execute_external_script  

    @language =N'Python',

    @script=N'
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import joblib

count_vect = joblib.load(''count_vect_V2.sav'')
tfidf_transformer = joblib.load(''tfidf_transformer_V2.sav'')
model_svm = joblib.load(''cs_svm_V2.sav'')
model_rf = joblib.load(''cs_rf_V2.sav'')
model_nb = joblib.load(''cs_nb_V2.sav'')
model_nn = joblib.load(''cs_nn_V2.sav'')
model_ensemble = joblib.load(''cs_ensemble_V2.sav'')

#Do something below


#End of doing something
    '
```

Is there a solution for storing these objects/libraries for my code to access so that I don't have to load them every time the script is run?

Comment: Have you tried [creating a model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/sqldev-py5-train-and-save-a-model-using-t-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Comment: I have various created models stored as .sav files, which get imported via my code above. The issue is that they take several seconds to import and I'm looking for a solution for not having to import them every time the procedure runs.

Comment: The procedure has to import those libraries every time, it's right there in the code with what you're asking it to do.  If they are large/complex and take a long time to load... there's not much that can be done about that with SQL Server and you're better off querying the data from SQL Server, sending it to an external scoring engine, then returning the result.

Comment: Right, was just wondering if there's some way to keep some sort of active session open with those objects imported.. Would you mind clarifying what you mean by sending to an external scoring engine?